# Do "almost surely" means probability 1 or approaching 1?

Tags: probability

When mathematicians say that something is almost surely to happens what does it means? Does it means that has probability 1 of happening or a value approaching 1?

Comment: It means probability equal to 1.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely

Comment: Add on to Lee's comment: You may also use "Asymptotically almost surely" to denote a sequence of probabilities approaching 1.

Comment: It is the probability equivalent of "almost everywhere" in analysis. Can be at most countably infinite points where it does not hold but their total measure is 0.

Comment: @ThomasGrubb, Or you may also use [*"with high probability"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_high_probability).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Almost surely" means that the probability is exactly equal to $1$. I think I know why such a question arises, so let me elaborate over an example.

Suppose we are tossing a coin $n$ times. What is the probability that we get at least one head? Well, the probability of this *not* happening is $\frac{1}{2^n}$, so the probability of there being some heads is $1-\frac{1}{2^n}$. This probability tends to $1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. So does this mean that if we toss a coin infinitely many times we are going to have at least one head *almost surely*?

The implication is not quite immediate. In certain way, throwing coin an infinite number of times is a "limit" of throwing coins $n$ times, and because of that in this "limit" the probability of getting at least one head is *equal* to $1$. So it is true that in infinite tosses we will get a head almost surely, *because that event has probability $1$*, but this is *implied* by the fact that the probabilities for finite number of tosses *tend* to $1$.

This distinction is important because in mathematics very often some processes cannot be thought of as "limits" of some finite processes (for example, randomly choosing a real number). In such contexts, speaking of the probability "approaching" $1$ simply doesn't make any sense. But an event has its own probability nevertheless, and it might be equal to $1$, in which case we say it happens almost surely.